# JSON.net string json into object

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Hey all I am having difficultys in making this string JSON that I have into an object so that I can use it like this:

```
json("go")("to")("needed")("spot").toString
```

and get my value.

Currently the XML to JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "UTF-8"
  },
  "data": {
    "recordCount": "1",
    "metadata": {
      "elementType": [
        {
          "name": "F_Paragraphtext",
          "uiType": "textArea",
          "dataType": "string",
          "label": "Text String",
          "dataLabel": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "records": {
      "F_Form1": {
        "@application_uid": "2a667c59-225c-4954-8e04-77bb083e5180",
        "@uid": "61f876f4-9760-4013-85bb-37965cff1fb6",
        "F_SingleLine": "test",
        "F_Paragraphtext": "{\"Data\":{\"DevisionName\":\"testing service after added field\",\"DevisionCode\":\"test\",\"CodeInString\":\"test^test|4/15/2015|50%|test^test|4/15/2015|25%|test^test|4/23/2015|50%~test^test|4/23/2015|N/A|test^test|4/8/2015|N/A|test^test|3/31/2015|N/A~test^test|4/10/2015|N/A|test^test|5/1/2015|50%|test^test|4/18/2015|N/A~test^test|3/30/2015|50%|test^test|4/24/2015|50%|test^test|5/9/2015|100%~test^test|3/30/2015|25%|test^test|3/30/2015|100%|test^test|4/11/2015|75%\"}}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I am trying to get the value for **F_Paragraphtext, @application_uid & @uid**.

The VB.net code I have:

```
Dim doc1 As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

   doc.LoadXml(serverResponse)
   Dim json1 As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)

   jsreader = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(New StringReader(json1))

   Try
       json = DirectCast(New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer().Deserialize(jsreader), Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.Message)
   End Try

   For Each Row In json("data")("records")(febFormID)
       Try
           dName = json("@application_uid").ToString
       Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.Message)
       End Try
   Next
```

While **Row** value is:

```
{"@application_uid": "2a667c59-225c-4954-8e04-77bb083e5180"}
```

The error falls on the **dName = Row("@application_uid").ToString**. The error is *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*.

Not quite sure what all I am missing in order to be able to retrieve the Row values but apparently its something....

Comment: Why are you converting XML into JSON into an object? While not just deserialize your XML?

Comment: @ScottSimontis Example?

Comment: I am just a little confused with what you are trying to do. Could you please explain what you are trying to do with this code from a high level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*...making this string JSON that I have into an object so that I can use it like this:*

```
json("go")("to")("needed")("spot").toString
```

*I am trying to get the value for F_Paragraphtext, @application_uid & @uid.*

```
Dim jstr As String = File.ReadAllText(filename)

Dim myJ = JObject.Parse(jstr)
Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", "F_Paragraphtext", 
        myJ("data")("records")("F_Form1")("F_Paragraphtext"))
Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", "@application_uid", 
        myJ("data")("records")("F_Form1")("@application_uid"))
Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", "@uid", 
        myJ("data")("records")("F_Form1")("@uid"))
```

Output:

> F_Paragraphtext == {"Data":{"DevisionName":"testing service after added field","DevisionCode":"test","CodeInString":"test^test|4/15/2015|50%|test^test|4/15/2015|25%|test^test|4/23/2015|50%~test^test|4/23/2015|N/A|test^test|4/8/2015|N/A|test^test|3/31/2015|N/A~test^test|4/10/2015|N/A|test^test|5/1/2015|50%|test^test|4/18/2015|N/A~test^test|3/30/2015|50%|test^test|4/24/2015|50%|test^test|5/9/2015|100%~test^test|3/30/2015|25%|test^test|3/30/2015|100%|test^test|4/11/2015|75%"}}
>   @application_uid == 2a667c59-225c-4954-8e04-77bb083e5180
>   @uid == 61f876f4-9760-4013-85bb-37965cff1fb6